# Revolution Slider next/previous buttons are not accessible

Tags: wordpress, slider, accessibility

This site (http://blindsa.org.za/) has been created for the Blind and needs to be fully accessible, however the screen reader is only reading 'Clickable' for the next & previous buttons on the revolution slider images that are at the top of the home page. Is there any way that I can change this to next slide and previous slide?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tab to the next/prev buttons so I can't hear what the screen reader will say when focus goes to them.  They're just <div> tags.  There are several things you can do to help, if you have access to the html.  These should all be added to the <div> tag.

1. add tabindex=0 so that I can tab to the buttons
2. add role=button so that I know it's a button
3. add aria-label='previous slide' and aria-label='next slide' so that I know what the buttons are for
4. add a keyboard handler (probably for onkeyup) so that I can hit space or enter to activate the button